# Unable to delete Recovery Service Vault in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I had created a RSV for practice and had a VM and file storage as backup items. Later I deleted the backup items and the VM and storage resource. Yet when i delete the vault i get this error about an existing resource which in fact does not exist.

[image]

There are no backup items for the vault

[image]

There are no backup jobs, policies , literally anything attached to the VM

[image]

The resource group has nothing except the vault

[image]

I have deleted everything possible and yet I am not able to delete the vault itself

Comment: Have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-delete-vault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to Delete Recovery Service Vault in Azure

In my environment, I encountered the same error:

> Vault Deletion Error: Recovery Services Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the vault: X venkat9801, venkat789. Please ensure all containers have been unregistered from the vault and all private endpoints associated with the vault have been deleted, and retry the operation. For more details

[image]

To delete the Recovery Service Vault, first, you need to unregister your storage account from the Recovery Service Vault.

To unregister, ***Go to Portal -> Your Recovery Service Vault -> Backup Infrastructure -> Storage Accounts -> Unregister.***

**Portal:**

[image]

After unregistering the storage accounts, I was able to delete my Recovery Service Vault.

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: I did not know how this got created in the vault. Thank you for taking the time to help. I was able to delete it now